# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type audio/mpeg

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

There are a number of questions starting with

[*Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type* **audio/mpeg**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Resource%20interpreted%20as%20Document%20but%20transferred%20with%20MIME%20type)

I have a javascript function which plays my sound. Works great, is simple and thin.

```
function Play(mp3Path)
{
    $("#sound_").remove();
    $('#soundEvent').html('<embed id="sound_" autostart="true" hidden="true" 
        src="' + mp3Path + '" type="audio/mpeg" />');
    //Line above formatted for readability
}
```

When i execute the above function, I get the following warning in chrome.
`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type audio/mpeg`

[image]

My attempt to fix involved adding the type attribute to the embed element.

Is there a way to get rid of that warning *without* major changes to code or going to HTML5/flash?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, get rid the warning buy you can hide it:

```
console.groupCollapsed(' ');console.log('just example');console.groupEnd(); console.log('b')
```

Comment: sounded promising. Did not work.